# I want my background to scroll slower than my content

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'd like my background to scroll slower than my page content. My background is in my body. No in div class "stuff" 
Please don't mark this as "someone's already asked this" as I've looked at those, and they haven't worked for me. I think it's an older version of HTML or JavaScript. Not sure though
If you think there's a problem, here's my code

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="mstile-70x70.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="mstile-150x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="mstile-310x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="mstile-310x310.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div class = "navbar">

        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <iframe     src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4sgdhg1/n103/fn4/fs16/fc00f/tct/pct/ahl/    avt/ftb/bas3/bat0/bac00f/pa8/tt0/tw1/th2/ta1/tb4" frameborder="0"           width="198"height="56" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

        </div>
          <div class = "stuff">
        <center>
            <br><br>
        Content Not Yet Added... :(
        </body>
        </div>
        <div class = "footer">
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </center>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url("background.jpg");
background-color: orange;
background-attachment: fixed;
}


.stuff{
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
position: inherit;
height: auto;
width:100%;
}


.navbar{
margin-top: -10px;
z-index: 1;
height: 9%;
position:fixed;
width: 98.7%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.21);
margin-bottom: 20%;
}


.footer {
width: 640px;
margin: 0% -320px;
height:44px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
/* not written yet */
```

Comment: What's your question? What's the issue? Why did you include a JavaScript section if there is no code?

Comment: Look at the heading thank you

Comment: I want my background to scroll slower than my page content

Comment: I added all of my codes just in case there may be any errors

Comment: And I included JavaScript so People could see that JavaScript wasn't my problem because there  _is_ no JavaScript

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read through the [help pages on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question. In particular, you want to make your code as readable as possible: cut it down to a minimal size that still demonstrates your point (e.g. `favicon` stuff has nothing at all to do with your question), and rename things so they make sense (`.stuff` - we don't need an explanation for it, but it should not be named `.stuff`, for one thing; don't let me get started on `.navbar`. If you have time for a silly comment, you have time to fix it).

Comment: There may have been an issue with my current code that would keep my last 10 hours of research from working, thank you very much.

Comment: You might have better luck if you move your code to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Right now it's difficult to see what attempts you've made to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Also consider removing what isn't necessary to your problem (which is a good problem solving strategy in any case). I very much doubt that any of the favicon link tags have any effect on the scrolling of your webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might set you on the right track. Look up "parallax scrolling"

Here is a website with demos:

```
http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/parallax-scrolling-1131762
```

To get started, check out this tutorial (It might not be exactly what you need but you will get the picture):

```
https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/
```

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you. Finally someone that actually wants to fix my issue

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please accept it :)

Comment: however, not quite what I was looking for

Comment: Well what exactly are you trying to do? Parallax scrolling isn't helpful?

Comment: @AHolasek Perhaps you could clarify why this answer wasn't what you were looking for.  Based on the current state of your question, parallax scrolling seems to be exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Parallax scrolling is to make the background hold multiple images, however i just want to change how much the scrolling affects the body background.